# Clang built from source handles `--sysroot` differently from nightly packages

Tags: c, llvm, cross-compiling, sysroot

Generally calling clang as a cross compiler:

```
clang --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu -xc -E -v /dev/null
```

Prints messages like:

```
Found candidate GCC installation: [...]
Found candidate GCC installation: [...]
```

and then goes on to use the associated include directories in the default search path, and I get what I want.

However, if I add `--sysroot=XXX`, then the clang I build from source abandons its GCC installation search, does not update the system include search path, and I end up with errors about missing headers because they're not present in the specified sysroot tree.

Whereas the packaged clang still finds the original GCC installations and extends the include search path accordingly, and then I can find headers provided either by the specified sysroot or the base system.

How did I end up with a different policy from the packaged version, and how do I fix it?

Also why?  What's the background to the variability of policies like this?  I'm clearly lacking the proper mental model to reason these things through.

Comment: I'd expect `--sysroot` to isolate the Clang from the rest of the system. You said your "packaged clang" behaves differently, where did you get this package? What OS?

Comment: I'd second @HolyBlackCat - sysroot should isolate from everything else, so the behavior of your "packaged clang" is questionable. Maybe someone added custom patches on top of it to break the proper behavior

Comment: Packages which do _not_ isolate from the local system are provided at: https://apt.llvm.org/

Maybe it's a bug?  Thing is, I've come into this from the point of "here's a rig which works" and part of "works" involves the upstream packages behaving this way, so my private build needs to emulate that.  Bug or not.